# user control inside server control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, servercontrol

I working on an asp.net app.  I'm have a user control inside a server control, say:

```
<sc:MyServerControl ID=...>
     <uc:MyUserControl>

     </uc:MyUserControl> 
</sc:MyServerControl>
```

But it seems that when I use the user control inside the server control, user control doesn't get loaded.  I tried putting a break point at the beginning of the `Page_Load` method but it doesn't stop there.

tks

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

For this to work you must make changes to the code of the server control. It should have a property of type UserControl and expect this property to be set as an inner property (as opposed to an attribute, like `ID="..."`). For this to work you should add attributes to the server control class that instruct the ASP.NET parser how to handle inner properties.

For more details, please refer to this article:

[The ParseChildren, PersistChildren and PersistenceMode.InnerProperty](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2008/07/27/parsechildren-persistchildren-persistencemode.innerproperty.aspx)

Comment: Got similar problem and that not the solution.

Comment: @Rushino can you post your solution?